# Regex: check if string match multiple substrings in random order

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind, playing-cards

I have a string that is always in the following pattern:

```
"AB AB AB AB AB "   // (note the trailing space)
```

Where `A` can be any character in `"12345678TJQKA"`, and `B` can be any character in `"HSCD"` (basically the 52 playing cards).

How can I check if this String is for example a Royal Flush with a regex?

Some things I tried without result (just using Diamonds for now) (NOTE: I have no idea how to properly use look-aheads, look-behinds, and look-arounds, so I most likely do <s>something</s> everything wrong..)

```
^(?=AD )(?=KD )(?=QD )(?=JD )TD $
^(?=AD .*)(?=KD .*)(?=QD .*)(?=JD .*)TD .*$
^(?=AD )(?=KD )(?=QD )(?=JD )(?=TD )$
^(?=AD .*)(?=KD .*)(?=QD .*)(?=JD .*)(?=TD .*)$
^(?<=AD )(?<=KD )(?<=QD )(?<=JD )(?<=TD )$
```

So I want the regex to match `"AD KD QD JD TD "` in any order (so including for example its reversed (`"TD JD QD KD AD "`) or in this random order: `"KD TD QD AD JD "`). Preferably with a capture group for `D` as well so it's uniform for all four suits..

[Here is an online regex tester with some test cases in case anyone want to fuddle around.](https://regex101.com/r/eR9kQ6/22)

If you have a regex that not only matches for Diamond Royal Flush, but for all suits at the same time (with explanation of how it works) that would be even better. (Any other method to check for Royal Flush instead of regex is fine as well, but I'd still like to know how this can be done in regex as well, since that is where my question is mainly about.)

Comment: I think you're going to either have to use really ugly alternations, or many lookarounds.  In any case, I am not sure that a pure regex solution would fit your problem best, because a given player's hand can be in any order.  A better approach to find a straight, or a straight flush, might be to sort the hand by rank, and then check it using string functions (possibly involving some regex also).

Comment: i'm not sure but did you mean this https://ideone.com/QQNcj6

Comment: @YCF_L Not exactly, because it also returns success for `"TC JD QD KD AD "` or `"1D JD QD KD AD "` now, which aren't Royal Flushes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to check this, though it might not be the best way to do this.

My answer has the assumption that all strings are proper entries (5 cards in your given format).

We can then use

```
^(?=.*J(\w))(?=.*Q\1)(?=.*T\1)(?=.*K\1)(?=.*A\1).*$
```

To check if it is a royal flush. We use a bunch of lookaheads to check the needed cards and in the first try match the used suit and ruse it with a backreference. We can simply use `\w` to check the suit, as the identifiers of card type and suit don't overlap (even `.` should be possible)

See https://regex101.com/r/eR9kQ6/23

Comment: Why the `.+` instead of `.*` before the `Q` btw? Does that have a reason, or is it a typo?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen typo